# getJSON, SyntaxError: missing : after property id

Tags: jquery, json

I can't find what is wrong. I use getJSON:

```
    $.getJSON(api,  
    {
        Content-Type : 'application/json'
    }).done(function( data ) 
    {
        $(data).each(function(key,val){
            console.log(val.calories)
        });

    }).fail( function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);              
    });
```

and console returns me:

```
SyntaxError: missing : after property id
```

pointing to line

```
Content-Type : 'application/json'
```

Comment: Yes, that line is wrong. Since you aren't SENDING data, you can simply remove it. http://api.jquery.com/ajax/

Comment: The syntax for `$.getJSON` is *NOT* the same as `$.ajax`.  Just remove that line (and even the entire object).  Just do: `$.getJSON(api).done(...)`

Comment: Even though you are both correct, you're not telling him why the error occurs in the first place. See my answer for a little bit more detail.

Comment: @KevinB 
when I remove that line I get "undefined error"

Comment: @MehmetInce 
It's not duplicate...

Comment: @MrJedi if removing the line gives undefined error, you didn't remove it correctly. (the whole object has to be removed.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual error is that {} is an object literal (I like to think of those as dictionaries, key-value pairs).
The notation of an object literal is as follow:

```
var literal = {
    key: value,
    anotherKey, anotherValue
};
```

The problem with your line of code is that the 'key' is Content-Type. However, a dash in the key is not allowed. You can fix it by putting quotes around it:

```
{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
```

But, as said in the comments, you really don't have to set that option here. So you can just remove the object literal.

Comment: It not work.
Removing option or add quotes causes "undefined error"

Comment: So actually it DID work. It removed your error. You now have a different error.

Where does that error appear? What have you done yourself to debug it? Does the server call work and return anything before the error hits?

Comment: This code block probably won't work:

`$(data).each(function(key,val){ console.log(val.calories) });`

because 'data' is json, and $() is used on DOM elements. Try debugging one step at a time and figure out what works and what doesn't.